# Merging newline separated strings

Tags: sh, posix

Let's say I have two variables *foo* and *bar* containing the same number of newline separated strings, for instance

```
$ echo $foo
a
b
c
$ echo $bar
x
y
z
```

What is the simplest way to merge *foo* and *bar* to get the output below?

```
a x
b y
c z
```

If *foo* and *bar* were files I could do `paste -d ' ' foo bar` but in this case they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use process substitution in Bash to do this (not POSIX compliant):

```
foo=$'a\nb\nc'
bar=$'x\ny\nz'
paste -d ' ' <(printf '%s\n' "$foo") <(printf '%s\n' "$bar")
```

Outputs:

```
a x
b y
c z
```

An sh-compliant way seems a little convoluted:

```
foo=$'a\nb\nc'
bar=$'x\ny\nz'
res=$(while IFS=$'\n' read -u 3 -r f1 && IFS=$'\n' read -u 4 -r f2; do
  printf '%s' "$f1"
  printf ' %s\n' "$f2"
done 3<<<"$foo" 4<<<"$bar"
)
```

Comment: You might want to remove the `POSIX` compliance word for the last snippet, because neither the ANSI quoted strings `$'..'` nor the here-strings are `POSIX sh` shell compliant

Comment: Also process substitution is also bourne-again shell specific feature and _not_ `POSIX` bourne `sh` shell compatible. The question was meant for the latter shell.

Comment: Thanks @Inian - updated the answer.  The second solution did work with `sh`.

Comment: I think you got confused with what the `POSIX` and the bourne  shell `sh`, one most of the distros, `sh` is linked to `bash`, in which case, all the scripts that run in `bash` would run here too. But when you updated it to `sh` compliant, it gives the wrong meaning, the actual `sh` is _not_ `bash`, See more on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell

Comment: My `sh` isn't linked to `bash`.

Comment: Also, to check your script for `POSIX` compliant, download the utility shellcheck from GitHub and run `shellcheck --shell=sh <script-name>` to see if its reporting any errors. Am guessing you will see errors in the places I mentioned

Comment: Have a look at here, installed it myself https://gist.github.com/inianv/9219ff9955bc0dd251055c319eb8868f

Comment: `mkfifo p1 p2; printf '%s\n' "$foo" > p1 & printf '%s\n' "$bar" > p2; paste -d ' ' p1 p2; rm p1 p2`. Process substitution is in some sense just syntactic sugar to make using named pipes easier.